# Abstract class with maximum member of given classes

Tags: c#, abstract

I've exercise question below

Write `Class1`, `Class2` and `Class3` content inherited from the abstract class (unlike interface usage, the default class contents will change as a result of override operations on the abstract members of the classes).

The abstract class should be written for the highest possible number of members.
These are `class1`,`class2`, and `class3` below

```
class Class1 : ClassAbs
{
    public int number1;
    protected double _prop1;
    public double property1 { set { _prop1 = value; } }
    public int property2 { get; }
    public int method1(int x) { return x * x * x; }
}
class Class2 : ClassAbs
{
    public int number1;
    public double property1 { get; set; }
    public int method1(int x) { return x * x; }
}
class Class3 : ClassAbs
{
    public int number1;
    public double property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Also, there's a tip: `ClassAbs` represents the abstract class in the given template. Some members
of `Class1`, `Class2`, and `Class3` classes can be found either as complete or just as prototypes.

In the abstract class, both the completed members and the
prototype descriptions (declaration lines) can be used.

I didn't understand the question well so wanted to ask you.

My solution is identifying intersections and inserting into abs class. Variable number1 is common for all classes so put inside Abs class.

And also wanted to put prop1 as an abstract method to override inside classes.

But I couldn't do that.

Here's what I tried what do you think?I'm sure some parts of it missing.

```
abstract class ClassAbs
{
    public int number1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. I'd listen to what they say about how inheritance works, but please don't trust what they say about *when to use inheritance* unless they tell you to to use it cautiously. For example, if you had three classes with one or a few properties in common, that doesn't mean that they should necessarily be extracted into an abstract class. Hopefully that's not what they're suggesting. For some odd reason a lot of material shows how inheritance works and makes it look like a solution to all sorts of problems, when just as often it ends up being the problem that needs a solution.